# Laravel Custom Pivot Table relationship and eager loading?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I am having problems with creating a schema / model for one of my projects and would like to get some help here.

I have 3 tables currently : accessories , products and a pivot table product_accessory

```
<?php 

Schema::create('accessories', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
}

Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table) 
{
    $table->increments('id');
}

Schema::create('product_accessory', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('accessory_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
    $table->foreign('accessory_id')->references('id')->on('accessories');
}
```

Now problem is I need to add another product type 'adaptors' that would ultimately depend on the pivot table relation, that is, adaptors need to relate to both a product and accessory...

**UPDATE** 
Here is how my current product_accessory_adaptor table is

```
Schema::create('product_accessory_adaptor', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('product_accessory_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('product_accessory_id')->references('id')->on('product_accessory');
}
```

This way, i can have many adaptors relating to a product and accessory. My question is how do i model this relation in eloquent?

Here's what i have now:

Custom pivot model :

```
class ProductAccessory extends Pivot {
   protected $table = 'product_accessory';

   public function product()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('Product');
   }

   public function accessory()
   {
     return $this->belongsTo('Accessory');
   }

   public function adaptors() {
     return $this->hasMany('Adaptor', 'product_accessory_id'); 
   } 
}
```

Product and Accessory model

```
class Accessory extends Eloquent {

   public function products()
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Product', 'product_accessory', 'accessory_id', 'product_id')->withPivot();
   }

   public function newPivot(Eloquent $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists) 
   {
      if ($parent instanceof Product) {
          return new ProductAccessory($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
      }
      return parent::newPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
   }

   public function adaptors()
   {
      return $this->hasManyThrough('Adaptor', 'ProductAccessory', 'accessory_id', 'product_accessory_id');
   }
}

class Product extends Eloquent {

   public function accessories()
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Accessory', 'product_accessory', 'product_id', 'accessory_id')->withPivot();
   }

   public function newPivot(Eloquent $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists) 
   {
      if ($parent instanceof Accessory) {
          return new ProductAccessory($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
      }
      return parent::newPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
   }

   public function adaptors()
   {
      return $this->hasManyThrough('Adaptor', 'ProductAccessory', 'product_id', 'product_accessory_id');
   }
}
```

Adaptor model:

```
class Adaptor extends Eloquent {

   protected $table = 'product_accessory_adaptor';

   public function productAccessory() {
      return $this->belongsTo('ProductAccessory');
   }
}
```

**Update**
Now the schema and model is setup. However there are issues with using hasManyThrough relations. In addition, any way to do eager loading in this case for the pivot relation , i.e Adaptor?

**Note**
The error that occurs when i make a call to adaptors() on either the Product or Accessory model is 
    `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, none given, called in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 872 and defined`

Comment: You need this: **1** custom pivot model `ProductAccessory`, **2** 2 `belongsTo` relations on this model (with `Product` and `Accessory`) + `hasMany` relation with `Adaptor`, **3** Adaptor model with `belongsTo` relation to that pivot model, **4** `hasManyThrough` relations with `Adaptor` on both `Product` and `Accessory`. It may seem pretty complex, but give it a try.

Comment: hey @deczo thanks for the reply. i am trying to figure out how to do write the custom pivot model but can't seem to quite find examples on it. the documentation here http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables doesn't really provide an example on how to do it. would you mind giving me some directions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's your pivot:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

// you don't need to call it ..Pivot, just my suggestion
class ProductAccessory extends Eloquent {

  protected $table = 'product_accessory';

  public function product()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Product');
  }

  public function accessory()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Accessory');
  }

  public function adaptors()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('Adaptor', 'product_accessory_id');
  }
}

// Product model
public function adaptors()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
      'Adaptor', 'ProductAccessoryPivot', 'product_id', 'product_accessory_id'
    );
}

// Accessory model
public function adaptors()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
      'Adaptor', 'ProductAccessoryPivot', 'accessory_id', 'product_accessory_id'
    );
}
```

Now example usage:

```php
$product = Product::first();

$product->adaptors; // collection of all adaptors for given product

$product->adaptors->first()->accessory; // accessory for single adaptor

$product->accessories; // collection of accessories, each with your custom pivot, so:

$product->accessories->first()->adaptors; // collection of adaptors for given product-accessory pair

... and more, try it
```

Comment: hey @deczo i can now access the adaptors data via 
`$product->accessories()->first()->pivot->adaptors()` 
but not through 
`Product::first()->adaptors  or $product->accessories->first()->adaptors.` 

whenever i do that, this error occurs : `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, none given, called in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 872 and defined`

also, on a side note, is there anyway i can eager load the adaptors data?

Comment: Right, I forgot about it. In fact you don't need to extend `Pivot` but ordinary `Model`/`Eloquent`, and no need to use custom `newPivot`. Check the edit and it wil work.

Comment: great that finally worked! thanks alot. and i was able to use eager loading for the adaptor, essentially halving the speed of the queries.

Comment: sorry after changing to this method, my save for adaptor doesn't work now... how should i add an adaptor to the pivot table?

Comment: paste the code you execute and error to bin.laravel.io

Comment: OK, you still need custom pivot in order to use it the way you want: http://laravel.io/bin/eybn6

Comment: thanks for the suggesstion. got to say its quite brilliant. 
however, say if i don't need to save it this way (through the pivot), wat would be the correct way to save adaptors? retrieve product_accessory_id and use Adaptor::create? p.s thanks for the patience so far

Comment: Yes, you could simply do it manually `$adaptor = new Adaptor([your data here, 'product_accessory_id => $product_accessory->pivot->id]);` but then you need `withPivot(['id']);` on the `Product`-`Accessory` relations

Comment: hey deczo, sorry my requirements kind of change and i have no idea if should create a new question or ask u here on this. is there any way i can eager load the pivot relations with constraints? Something like this http://laravel.io/bin/Qk8BV. its possible to eager load with this but i can't figure out how to pass in the pivot id

Comment: Please ask a new question with appropriate code and description, what you'd like to query

Comment: sorry @deczo, here's the new question  :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995629/eager-loading-nested-relationships-using-pivot

Comment: I really need to see `laravel.io/bin/eybn6`. Unfortunately it just takes me to `laravel.io/bin` when I click the link. :( I am pretty sure it is a problem on their side because I can't load any pastebin stuff on their site.

Comment: Yes, it seems laravel.io broke something. Ask your question and I'll try to help you.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk I actually think I am starting to understand it a little more. I was mixing code from too many difference examples. Once I get a better grasp on how this is supposed to work I will make a tutorial and link to it in another comment.