# Eager loading nested relationships using pivot

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I have 4 tables currently :

```
accessories 
id 

products 
id

product_accessory 
id 
product_id
accessory_id 

product_accessory_adaptor
id 
product_accessory_id
```

Mapping them to Eloquent models gives me

Custom pivot model :

```
class ProductAccessory extends Pivot {
   protected $table = 'product_accessory';

   public function product()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('Product');
   }

   public function accessory()
   {
     return $this->belongsTo('Accessory');
   }

   public function adaptors() {
     return $this->hasMany('Adaptor', 'product_accessory_id'); 
   } 
}
```

Product and Accessory model

```
class Accessory extends Eloquent {

   public function products()
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Product', 'product_accessory', 'accessory_id', 'product_id')->withPivot();
   }

   public function newPivot(Eloquent $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists) 
   {
      if ($parent instanceof Product) {
          return new ProductAccessory($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
      }
      return parent::newPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
   }

   public function adaptors()
   {
      return $this->hasManyThrough('Adaptor', 'ProductAccessory', 'accessory_id', 'product_accessory_id');
   }
}

class Product extends Eloquent {

   public function accessories()
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Accessory', 'product_accessory', 'product_id', 'accessory_id')->withPivot();
   }

   public function newPivot(Eloquent $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists) 
   {
      if ($parent instanceof Accessory) {
          return new ProductAccessory($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
      }
      return parent::newPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
   }

   public function adaptors()
   {
      return $this->hasManyThrough('Adaptor', 'ProductAccessory', 'product_id', 'product_accessory_id');
   }
}
```

Adaptor model:

```
class Adaptor extends Eloquent {

   protected $table = 'product_accessory_adaptor';

   public function productAccessory() {
      return $this->belongsTo('ProductAccessory');
   }
}
```

Here's what i need. Eager loading all products with accessories with adaptors belonging to their pivot. I've tried something like this but i have no clue how to pass in the pivot id

in Product Model

```
public function accessories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Compatibility\Accessory', 'product_accessory', 'product_id', 'accessory_id')
                ->withPivot('id', 'accessory_disclaimer')
                ->withTimestamps()
                ->with(['adaptors' => function ($q) {
                    $q->where('product_accessory_id', $this->pivot->id);                       
                }]);
}
```

Does anyone has any clue how to do this? What should i replace with $this->pivot->id?

Comment: Please refer to the comments in your previous question about the Pivot model. Hope it's all clear.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to eager load anything related to the pivot model. It's not gonna work this way, so I suggest this:

```
$products->load('ProductAccessory.accessory', 'ProductAccessory.adaptors');

// then you access related accessory and adaptors through the pivot model
$product = $products->first();

$product->productAccessory->accessory;
$product->productAccessory->adaptors;

// Product model
public function productAccessory()
{
  return $this->hasMany('ProductAccessory');
}
```

note: `ProductAccessory` should extend `Eloquent` (`Model`), not `Pivot` - like I stated my answer to your previous question.

This is the way to have this in one place, ie. get related accessory and associated adaptors.

Otherwise you would need something like this:

```
$product->accessory; // accessory model, so far so good
$product->adaptors; // all adaptors, not so good anymore

// to get adaptors for the accessory we need:
$accessories = $product->adaptors()->where('product_accessories.id', $product->accessory->pivot->id)->get();
```

not very convenient..

Comment: actually this might help visualise what i'm trying to do for the output of json data: `products : [
       accessories : [                     // accessory belonging to a product 
  adaptors :      // adaptors belonging to a product and accessory 
 ]
]` i'm trying to load adaptors data into accessories with the correct constraint

Comment: I understand that, and this is why I suggested the solution above. You can easily do what you need with that approach, because `accessory` and its `adaptors` are coupled together by `productAccessory` object.

Comment: thanks @deczo i managed to build my data structure using your suggestion. however i could not hide the productAccessory property on product, any ideas? http://laravel.io/bin/4GydX

Comment: Unset it, hide using `$hidden` property, use transformer if it's API.